# showDialog not displayed Android

Tags: java, android, date, dialog

Inside an `Activity`, I am calling different fragments , I want the user to be able to change the date by clicking on a `textView` that displays the current date, the `showDialog` does not want to be displayed.

```
dateView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getActivity().showDialog(999);
    }
});
```

Android Studio tells me that `CreateDialog` is never used.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                myDateListener, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}
```

> Full code:

```
public class Fragment5 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private TextView dateView;
    TimePicker timePicker2;
    private int year, month, day;
    public Fragment5() {
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment5, container, false);
        dateView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        showDate(year, month+1, day);

        dateView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getActivity().showDialog(999);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (id == 999) {
            return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                    myDateListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0,
                                      int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // arg1 = year
                    // arg2 = month
                    // arg3 = day
                    showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
                }
            };

    private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
                .append(month).append("/").append(year));
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  public static Bundle myBundl = new Bundle();
private List<ItemSlideMenu> listSliding;
private SlidingMenuAdapter3 adapter;
private Calendar calendar;
private TextView dateView;
TimePicker timePicker2;
final Context context = this ;
private int year, month, day;
private ListView listViewSliding;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
String name1;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
showDate(year, month+1, day);
    //Init component
    listViewSliding = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    listSliding = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add item for sliding list
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.home_96,"Accueil" ));
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.cocktail,"Organiser une Sortie"));
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.geo,"Autour de moi"));
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ami,"Liste d'amis" ));
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.message,"Contact"));
    listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.information,"Credits"));

    adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter3(this, listSliding);
    listViewSliding.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Display icon to open/ close sliding list
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Set title
    setTitle(listSliding.get(0).getTitle());
    //item selected
    listViewSliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
    //Close menu
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);

    //Display fragment 1 when start
    replaceFragment(0);
    //Hanlde on item click

    listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Set title
            setTitle(listSliding.get(position).getTitle());
            //item selected
            listViewSliding.setItemChecked(position, true);

            if (position==2){
                Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i2);

            }   else
            {//Replace fragment
            replaceFragment(position);
            }//Close menu
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
        }
    });

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

//Create method replace fragment

private void replaceFragment(int pos) {

    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (pos) {

        case 0:

            fragment = new Fragment1();

            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        case 3 :
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            break;



    }

    if(null!=fragment) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_content,fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                myDateListener, year, month, day);
    }
    else if (id ==98) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button


        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment6 fragment = null;
                fragment = new Fragment6();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.contact, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    }


    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0,
                                  int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // arg1 = year
                // arg2 = month
                // arg3 = day
                showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
            }
        };

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

StringBuilder abbes = new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
            .append(month).append("/").append(year);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("edttext", String.valueOf(abbes));
    // set Fragmentclass Arguments
    Fragment5 fragobj = new Fragment5();
    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since,

> **Callback for creating `dialogs` that are managed (saved and restored) for you by the Activity.**

Implement this method in `Activity`instead of `Fragment`

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (id == 999) {
            return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                    myDateListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Call Fragment like this;

```
private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

StringBuilder abbes = new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
            .append(month).append("/").append(year);
    if(fragment instanceof Fragment4){
       ((Fragemnt4)fragment).dateView.setText(""+abbes);
    }

}
```

Make dateView public

Comment: Exactly.. because, Callback for creating `dialogs` that are managed (saved and restored) for you by the `Activity`.

Comment: The three methods are related, displaying the date and modifying it. if I put just this method ( 'Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)' ) in activity I would have an error 'myDateListener'
And if I put it all the date will not be changed on the textview that is in the fragment

Comment: You can change textview of fragment from activity

Comment: Post your activity code where you are adding your fragment

Comment: I tried to do that! Only activity returns ExceptionNullpointer in methode showdate in activty

Comment: Inconvertible types ; cannot cast int to "my_package".Fragment4

Answer (score 0):

showDialog() is deprecated. Replace this code

```
 public class Fragment5 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private DatePicker datePicker;
private Calendar calendar;
private TextView dateView;
TimePicker timePicker2;
private int year, month, day;
DialogFragment dateFragment;
public Fragment5() {
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment5, container, false);
    dateView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDate(year, month+1, day);

    dateView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {

             dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    dateFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}





private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
            .append(month).append("/").append(year));
}

class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
      showDate(year,month,day);
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly `showDialog (int id)` method does is show a dialog managed by `activity`. A call to `onCreateDialog(int, Bundle)` will be made with the same id the first time this is called for a given id. From thereafter, *the dialog will be automatically saved and restored.*

You must write your `onCreateDialog` method in `Activity` as said by @Burhanuddin Rashid but that could cause complexity in data transition between `Activity` and `Fragment`.

**Further**,

```
void showDialog (int id)
```

**This method was deprecated in API level 13.**
Use the new [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) class with [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

PS,
I recommend you to use a `DialogFragment`

For more info check out this [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)